# Using input of remote machine as input to my c program in ssh

Tags: c, ssh, raspberry-pi

I'm searching the internet for a day now and I couldn't find the answer. So I'm connecting from system A (my computer) through ssh to system B (my Raspberry pi) and try to run a program (in c not python) with the input given by something that acts like a keyboard on system B. Can someone explain how to do this? Thank you.

I tried using the function scanf(One who doesn't take risks will not win), but of course this didn't work.

After I tried to use a pipe from a separate program that logs the input of system B.

Then I was clueless hanging around on the internet, but couldn't find something about it.

Comment: Are you saying you want to write a program that acts like a person logged into a remote system, where it runs commands remotely over ssh?

Comment: Forgetting your PC for a minute, if you were sitting in front of your Raspberry Pi with a screen attached... how would you get anything from this *"keyboard-like"* device? Would you `cat` some file?